# Why do I get null when I try to show the email of the current Firebase user?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I been working trying to display the current user's email but it shows null. I'm using an some line of code that I saw in Stack Overflow where the user that posted it said that it will help get the email, but it's not working for some reason. the code is init user, where it's an asynchronous method.

Here's the code:

```
class MenuCentral extends StatefulWidget {
  final String name;
  MenuCentral({Key key, @required this.name,this.email,this.googleSignIn}) : super(key:key);
  final String email;
  final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn;
  @override
  _MenuCentralState createState() => _MenuCentralState();
}


class _MenuCentralState extends State<MenuCentral>{
   final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
   final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    FirebaseUser user;
    String email = '';
   
  initUser() async{
    user = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    setState(() {
      email = user.email.toString()
    });
  } 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    Widget  imgMovimiento = new Container(//imagenes en movimiento
    height: 200.0,
    child:  new Carousel(
      boxFit: BoxFit.cover,
      images: [
        AssetImage('images/perro.jpg'),
        AssetImage('images/gatos.jpg'),
        AssetImage('images/periquito.jpg'),
        
      ],
      autoplay: true,//mover img automatico o manual 
      animationCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
      animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 2),
      dotSize: 4.5,//tamano circulodebajo de imagenes
      indicatorBgPadding: 3,//tamano de franja debajo de las imagenes  
    ),
    
  );
    return Scaffold(
       appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.brown[600], //Color del bacground del titulo
        title:Text('Animal App') ,// Titulo de la app en el home page
        actions: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black87,), onPressed: (){})//boton de buscar
        ],
      ),
//--
        drawer: new Drawer(//menu lateral
        child: new ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
           // imgMovimiento,
         
//header   
          new UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
            accountName: Text('John'),
            
            accountEmail: Text("${user?.email.toString()}"),
            currentAccountPicture: GestureDetector( // foto de perfil
              child: new CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                child: Icon(Icons.person, color: Colors.black87),
              ),
            ),

            decoration: new BoxDecoration(//color menu lateral
              color: Colors.brown[600]
            ),
            ),
```

Comment: User accounts are not guaranteed to have an email address associated with them.  It will be null when missing.  Your code should check for that.

Comment: i used a print to check, and it does show the email. but i was wondering if you know how i can get a document that has the users email.